# Custom Inventory Source Item

Tags: magento2.4, uicomponent, multi-source-inventory, msi-source

I am trying to render the **extension_attibute** value from databases to show on UI component field for Custom Inventory Source Item (please refer following screenshot)

[image]

For that I have created -

1. create entension attribute for Magento\InventoryApi\Api\Data\SourceItemInterface
2. save the custom value into inventory source item table extend the below class vendor\magento\module-inventory\Model\ResourceModel\SourceItem\SaveMultiple.php

But not able to render value - trying plugin for Magento\InventoryApi\Api\SourceItemRepositoryInterface as follow -
di.xml added following -

```
<type name="Magento\InventoryApi\Api\SourceItemRepositoryInterface">
        <plugin name="Mastek_Inventory_SourceItemRepository"
                type="Custom\Inventory\Plugin\SourceItemRepository"/>
    </type>
```

and Custom\Inventory\Plugin\SourceItemRepository -

````
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Custom\Inventory\Plugin;

use Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensionAttributesFactory;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
use Magento\InventoryApi\Api\Data\SourceInterface;
use Magento\InventoryApi\Api\Data\SourceItemSearchResultsInterface;

use Magento\InventoryApi\Api\Data\SourceItemExtensionInterface;
use Magento\InventoryApi\Api\SourceItemRepositoryInterface;

use Magento\Inventory\Model\ResourceModel\SourceItem as SourceItemResourceModel;

use \Magento\Inventory\Model\SourceItem;



use Custom\Inventory\Api\Data\SourceItemInterface;

class SourceItemRepository
{
    protected const CUSTOM_STOCK = 'custom_stock';

    protected ExtensionAttributesFactory $extensionAttributesFactory;
    
    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function __construct(
        ExtensionAttributesFactory $extensionAttributesFactory
    ) {
        $this->extensionAttributesFactory = $extensionAttributesFactory;
    }    

    private function extendSource(SourceItem $source): void
    {        

        $extensionAttributes = $source->getExtensionAttributes();        

        $extensionAttributes->setCustomStock($source->getData(self::CUSTOM_STOCK));
    }

    

    public function afterGetList(
        SourceItemRepositoryInterface $subject,
        SourceItemSearchResultsInterface $sourceSearchResults
    ): SourceItemSearchResultsInterface {
        $items = $sourceSearchResults->getItems();
        
        array_walk(
            $items,
            [$this, 'extendSource']
        );

        return $sourceSearchResults;
    }
} ``` 

But Value not showing in fields 

I have use product_form.xml to add Custom Inventory Source Item - 

```<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="sources" sortOrder="5" >
        
        <dynamicRows name="assigned_sources" sortOrder="20">       
            
            
            <container name="record" component="Magento_Ui/js/dynamic-rows/record">         
                <field name="custom_stock" formElement="input" sortOrder="51" >
                    <settings>
                        <dataType>text</dataType>
                        <dataScope>extension_attributes.custom_stock</dataScope>
                        <label translate="true">Custom Stock Status</label>                        
                        <disabled>false</disabled>                                              
                    </settings>
                </field>                           
            </container>            
        </dynamicRows>
        
    </fieldset>
    
</form>
````

Please let me know is it correct way and where this goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

you need to alter your product_form.xml

ex I am adding yes/no field in this example :

```
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<fieldset name="sources">
    <dynamicRows name="assigned_sources">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="map" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source_code" xsi:type="string">source_code</item>
                    <item name="name" xsi:type="string">name</item>
                    <item name="custom_field" xsi:type="string">custom_field</item>
                    <item name="qty" xsi:type="string">qty</item>
                    <item name="source_status" xsi:type="string">enabled</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <container name="record" >
            <field name="custom_field" formElement="select" sortOrder="25">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="fit" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
                <settings>
                    <dataType>text</dataType>
                    <dataScope>custom_field</dataScope>
                    <label translate="true">Custom_Field</label>
                </settings>
                <formElements>
                    <select>
                        <settings>
                            <options class="Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno"/>
                        </settings>
                    </select>
                </formElements>
            </field>
        </container>
    </dynamicRows>
</fieldset>
```